# Determine if Sequence is Cauchy

Tags: cauchy-sequences

Can someone please tell me how to determine if a sequence is Cauchy without using the limit.  I'm supposed to use partial fraction decomposition

$a_n=\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$. When I did the partial decomposition I found $\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}$ but I don't know what to do from there.

Thank you

Comment: I think the partial decomposition should be $\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$ which is telescoping!!\

Comment: You should use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Posts that do not use MathJax tend to get less attention.

Comment: You seem to have two typos with the parenthesis, can you please edit your post and correct them? And don't forget to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make things easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

$|a_n| <\frac 1 n$ so $|a_n-a_m|\leq |a_n|+|a_m| <\frac 1 n+\frac 1 m<\epsilon$ if $n,m >\frac 2 {\epsilon}$.